# Apple Account Not have any Development Teams

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, account

I have logged in Xcode settings Accounts with my Apple ID and password, but still it's showing "Not on Any Development Teams". I am using Xcode 6.2.

[image]

Comment: And you are sure that you are a member of a development team?

Comment: yes, in other mac i can do the same.

Comment: Export your account from that mac and import it into this mac.

Answer (score 8):

This is an Xcode bug that has hit a lot of people. What seems to fix it is deleting the account from Xcode prefs using the "-" button, and then adding it back. I've done that on a couple of Macs, more than once, and it has always worked-- for a while. You may need to click "view details..." and then use the reload button afterward to ensure everything is up to date.

In case anyone from Apple happens to see this, please look up rdar://19870347

Comment: I tried to delete and added again. still having the same problem.

Comment: God bless you.  This was my main problem when completing this tutorial.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1#comments

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. I'm at a complete loss. I was seconds away from submitting and then I had an error, something about the app needing to request being sandboxed, and then I tried to build it and I have no development teams. No matter if I add or remove or restart or remove and restart and add and build, it doesn't matter! HELP PLEASE

Comment: Sorry, that's the only fix I know of, and obviously it doesn't work for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Download the provisioning profiles and certificates from the [Member Center](http://developer.apple.com) and save them to somewhere you can access them. Then, double-click the profiles and certificates. This should bring up Xcode as well as Keychain. You can dismiss the windows and that should work.

In Xcode, go to build settings and check that under Development and Distribution certificates the corresponding ones are correctly filled in.

Comment: I can Run the app in device from Xcode.  so not the provisioning profile issue.

Comment: So whats your problem then?

Comment: You should have to read the question properly (I have attached the  screen shot of the Accounts page and marked the issue in black ellipse)

Comment: 1. There is no question. 2. If you can use your iPhone then I don't know what the problem is. What do you want to do that you can't do right now?

Comment: Down voted my answer? Just because you're frustrated I'm right I guess...Well some people need that compensation...