# Development team is missing under Xcode 7 Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, organizer

When I tried to export an IPA for enterprise distribution on XCode 7, I cannot select the correct development team.

[image]
[image]

1. All teams are showing under XCode Preference > Profiles
2. I can see all the teams when I select a export method rather than Enterprise Distribution
   [image]
3. I have tried to remove and add the team again
4. I have checked that my developer account is not expired and there is no agreement pending for approval.
5. I have tried to restart XCode and my Mac, still no luck

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It is because the "WWDR intermediate certificate" from Apple is expired. You need to download the cert and remove the old one:

[Xcode 7 error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in Xcode. I have also faced this issue.

Try to to remove and re-add your Apple account within Xcode and refresh. also trying to create a new Apple profile (if you have not already done)so as their may be a conflict with current account.

You can find more info in this link also,

[apple-account-not-have-any-development-teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227604/apple-account-not-have-any-development-teams)